# Textbox in Angular modal showing previous value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my angular modal I have a dropdown, a textbox and a save button. Whenever I select a value in dropdown, enter any value in textbox and click on "save it"it works fine require. But on opening that model again I'm seeing the previously entered value in the textbox which I entered the last time I opened that modal.

Why is this happening and what is its solution?

Follows html:

```
<div bsModal #createSectionModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" (onShown)="onShown()" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createRoleModal" aria-hidden="true" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div #modalContent class="modal-content">
        <form *ngIf="active" #createSectionForm="ngForm" id="frm_create_section" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    <span>Create New Section</span>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group form-float">
                            <div class="form-line">
                                <select id="classname" required class="validate form-control" (change)="onClassChange($event)">
                                  <option value="?" selected="selected" novalidate></option>
                                  <option *ngFor="let class of classes | paginate: { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: pageSize, currentPage: pageNumber, totalItems: totalItems }" [value]="class.code">
                                   {{class.name}}
                                  </option>

                                </select>  
                                <label for="classname" class="form-label">Select Class</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row clearfix">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <div class="form-group form-float">
                          <div class="form-line">
                              <input id="name" name="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="section.name"  required maxlength="32" minlength="1" class="validate form-control">
                              <label for="name" class="form-label">Section Name</label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button [disabled]="saving" type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" (click)="close()">
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <button [disabled]="!createSectionForm.form.valid || saving" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect">
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the typescript files I'm binding the data with a property and then sending that data to a post request using service.
Tyepscript Code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injector, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild, 
ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/app-component-base';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SharedDataService } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';
import { CurriculumServiceProxy } from '@shared/service-proxies/service- 
 proxies';
 import { ClassDto, SectionDto,ListResultDtoOfCurriculumDto, 
  CreateSectionDto, CreateSectionResultDto, IListResultDtoOfCurriculumDto } 
  from '@shared/service-proxies/curriculumDtos';
  import { PagedListingComponentBase, PagedRequestDto } from 'shared/paged- 
 listing-component-base';


@Component({
selector: 'app-createsection',
templateUrl: './createsection.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./createsection.component.css']
})

 export class CreatesectionComponent extends AppComponentBase implements 
 OnInit {



@ViewChild('createSectionModal') modal: ModalDirective;
@ViewChild('modalContent') modalContent: ElementRef;

classes: ClassDto[] | undefined;
//subjects: SectionDto[] | undefined;
sections: SectionDto[] | undefined;
active: boolean;
saving: boolean;

section: CreateSectionDto = new CreateSectionDto();
sectionResult: CreateSectionResultDto = new CreateSectionResultDto();

@Output() modalSave: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

constructor(
injector: Injector,
private router: Router,
private _curriculumService: CurriculumServiceProxy,
private _sharedDataService: SharedDataService
) {
super (injector) 
}

onShown(): void {
$.AdminBSB.input.activate($(this.modalContent.nativeElement));
}

ngOnInit() {
this._curriculumService.getAllClassesWithDetail(this.appSession.tenant.tenancyName)
.finally(() => {this.saving = false;})
.subscribe((result: ListResultDtoOfCurriculumDto) => {
  this.classes = result.items;
})
}

save() : void {
this.saving = true;
this.section.schoolName = this.appSession.tenant.tenancyName;
this._curriculumService.CreateSection(this.section)
.finally(() => {
  this.saving = false;
})
.subscribe((result: CreateSectionResultDto) => {
  this.notify.info(this.l('Saved Successfully'));
  this.sectionResult = result;
  this.close();
  this.modalSave.emit(null);
})
}

show(): void {
this.active = true;
this.modal.show();
}

close(): void {
this.active = false;
this.modal.hide();
}

onClassChange(event) {
let selectedValue: string = event.target.value;
this.section.classCode = selectedValue;
}

}
```

Comment: Please, add the the typescript code in here so we can analyse better your problem. Thank you

Comment: I have added it. You can analyze it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get it fixed by just resetting the form. It wasn't because of any property that was left live so just reset the form and it will work. All you had to do was just call a simple reset function with `ngSubmit property like this (ngSubmit)="save(); createSectionForm.reset()"`

Answer (score 0):

The reference to the `section` is still live and the value persists between multiple modal opens. You either need to clear the modal data when it opens or after it saves. You can clear the data by assigning a new value to the object like so:

```
this.section = new CreateSectionDto();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by just resetting the form. It wasn't because of any property that was left live so i decided to just reset the form and it worked. All i had to do was just call a simple reset function with my ngSubmit property like this `(ngSubmit)="save(); createSectionForm.reset()"`

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.